# sql multiple rows replace

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a questions regarding SQL in MS Access. I have a column of numbers. There is a country name for every number in an Excel table. I replace one number after another in the following way:

1. Copy "country name" excel
2. Right-click on the column access
3. Find & replace
4. Replace all and so on.

Is there any code which can be used to replace all the rows in a column according to every number country's names? 
 [image]

and a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_oty30ONz0)

Comment: Plz SHOW us your table structure ( DDL ), and your data.   The verbal description is just to ambiguous to figure out what you are doing.   And, show us an example of the results you are after.

Comment: I have attached a file. Please download it. I am not eligible to post pictures yet. It is in Russian but the column I need to replace cells in is in English "Country of origin".

Comment: I can't read a RAR file on current machine.   Later today I'll have a look.  Maybe someone else can get to it sooner.   Sorry.

Comment: Add your picture in another site (imgur.com then add the link) or just draw your table structure in plain text, convert que column names to english. We just need to see.

Comment: Here is a link to imgur.com : http://imgur.com/rWGJ0S7 "Country of origin" is the colunmnu I need to replace numbers with names which are in an excel file.

Comment: Here is link to a file in an access format! http://we.tl/L4g9zL8mMk

Comment: Here is a link to a youtube video. I recorded a process of replacing. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_oty30ONz0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by writing an update query, which evaluates the current value, and conditionally replaces it:

```
UPDATE Tab_3 SET Country_Of_Origin =  

SWITCH(Country_Of_Origin = "001", "France",
Country_Of_Origin = "002", "Brazil",
TRUE, Country_Of_Origin);
```

Of course, you will need to add all the before/after pairs to replace my examples of "001"  being replace by "France" and "002" being replace by "Brazil"  ... so that it matches the new values from your spreadsheet.

If any problems, let me know.

Comment: Thank you Juan-Carlos, I wrote a code but a message box said that an expression was too complex. I have two questions: 1) How can I overcome this issue? If I need to shorten a code: 2) What do I need to write at the end so as numbers, which are not included in a quere stay unchanged? So that I can run this code several times. (when I wrote Country_of_origin = "894", "Zambia", TRUE, "Country_of_origin" - cells take "country_of_origin". IF I write FALSE instead of true, they become blank) Thank you.

Comment: There are 249 expressions: Country of origin = "840", "USA". A message box says that an expression in a query is too complex.

Comment: As you have indicated, running it multiple times, covering just a portion of the cases each time, is what I would suggest.   First try 25 different cases, it it handles that, go up to 50, and so on.    As for leaving numbers unchanged, I planned for that :   The last expression in the Switch Statement specifies the InputField ["Country_Of_Origin"] so if none of the code values in the expression are found, the starting value ["Country_Of_Origin"]  is used.      Naturally, test this all out on a TEST copy of your data.

Comment: You know, another alternative would be to create a new table containing the list of Country_IDs ( example 840 ) and the Country Name ( "USA" ) and when you query your base table, you join to the Country table to get the name.   This way you can just just the data you already have without having to do edits.   Further, if a country name changes, you only have to update one record in the Country table and you are done.   Something to think about....

Comment: Juan-Carlos, thank you very much for your assistance. I run the code, it works but the query changes the numbers which I do not include in the query into "Country_of_origin". Is there anything I can do? Have a look at the picture. http://imgur.com/VtrMkvi I tried to swith two numbers. I can not run a code on the same table again.

Comment: I see what happened.   The value at the end of that expression is the literal "Country_Of_Origin"   and it should have been a variable :   Country_Of_Origin.    It looks like you will need make that logic change AND go to a backup copy of the file and start running the changes over again.   Do you still have the original input data to start over with ?

Comment: yes, I run all the time on the copy. You mean I need to delete "quotation marks" around Country_of_origin? I will try now............I have deleted quotations marks and The rest of the cells became blank. It did not work

Comment: I don't know why its not working for you.  I worked on my home machine.  In a few hours I will be back to that machine and do some more experimenting.    Will let you know what I find.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked!=) I am very grateful to you! I do not quite understand how the last expression works TRUE, Country_of_origin, but thank you indeed!

Comment: yes=) Country_of_origin was not the same as the name of a column and it shown a mistake. Now everything worked perfectly!

Comment: Great !   Glad I was able to help you along.